# WordPress Dashboard Showing as some encoded text

Tags: php, wordpress, dashboard

I am trying to login to my WordPress site but it shows this text as a result. I have enabled WP_DEBUG but cant find a solution.

[image: WordPress dashboard error]

Comment: Your WordPress setup may have become corrupted for some reason. Try [reinstalling WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/how-to-install-wordpress/#detailed-instructions) (skip steps 2 and 5) and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Maybe dont completely reinstall wp. I would first try to see if it helps to disable one or more plugins or the theme. I would first change the folder name of some of the pluginns to disable them. But im not very sure. Dont do anything before you get a better answer.